# How to implement data filtering in mysql EAV model

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, entity-attribute-value

I have a table created in EAV model in mysql my biggest problem is how to do data filtering like ecommerce website let me show some of data and what i really want to achieve

i have a table named value in this i have four columns

```
id product_id  Attribute_name Attribute Value
1     1          Brand           Apple
2     1          Model           Iphone6
3     1          Color           White
4     1           OS             ios

5     2          Brand           Samsung
6     2          Model           Note4
7     2          Color           Black
8     2          OS              Android 

9     2          Brand           SONY
10    2          Model           Xperia
11    2          Color           Red
12    2          OS              Android
```

and i want to create all 4 filtering table suppose  someone checks the apple and samsung then only two model have to appears Iphone6 and Note4 and then when user checks on Iphone6 only white in color and ios in operating system appears how to do this please i want the solution very badly for 2 days

Comment: Would you like to give more information about what you're looking for as I don't know if the answers given so far have worked for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your table structure so that `Brand`, `Model`, `Color` and `OS` are attributes would make life easier, but assuming that there's some good reason why you can't transform it, I recommend a nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM value WHERE product_id = (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM value
     WHERE Attribute_name = 'Brand'
     AND Attribute_value = 'Apple'
);
```

That will return all the information relating to Apple products.  If you want to filter that list so you just get a list of models, append conditions to the outer query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM value WHERE product_id = (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM value
     WHERE Attribute_name = 'Brand'
     AND Attribute_value = 'Apple'
)
AND Attribute_name = 'Model';
```

There's a good analysis here of the pros and cons of EAV model:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#EAV_versus_row_modeling

If you want to pull multiple matches, you can `OR` together the nested queries:

```
SELECT * FROM value WHERE product_id = (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM value
     WHERE Attribute_name = 'Brand'
     AND Attribute_value = 'Apple'
) OR product_id = (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM value
     WHERE Attribute_name = 'Brand'
     AND Attribute_value = 'Samsung'
)
AND Attribute_name = 'Model';
```

If you want to pull multiple matches at multiple levels, you can keep nesting up the stack:

```
SELECT * FROM value WHERE product_id = (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM value
     WHERE Attribute_name = 'Brand'
     AND Attribute_value = 'Apple'
) OR product_id = (
     SELECT product_id
     FROM value
     WHERE Attribute_name = 'Brand'
     AND Attribute_value = 'Samsung'
)
AND Attribute_name = 'Model'
AND (Attribute_value = 'iPhone' OR Attribute_value = 'S3');
```

Comment: and what to do if more than 1 value is checked suppose user checked both samsung and apple and after that checks two model note4 and iphone6 and then select ios os and then the color checkbox appears related all the apple iphone6 having ios os white color.How do to multilevel filtering with EAV model i hope you understand my problem i want same filtering like ecommerce website have but In EAV model

Comment: I understand you want it like an eCommerce website, but few facetted searches (which is the functionality you're eluding to) allow you to select multiple facets at each level (e.g. Apple and Samsung, iPhone and S3).  They generally work by progressively restricting your search, e.g. show all products, then filter by Apple, show Apple products and revise downstream filters to only show Apple-product-options.

Comment: you are trying to say that when user clicks on brand checkbox then i have to create model options and further that os option is this you are trying to tell

Comment: I think your terms are a little confused but essentially yes.  Each click on a checkbox represents the application of a filter, which impacts the dataset, but also the list of other filters.